# The operator == is undefined for the argument type(s) long, null

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Trying to insert a course object into the H2 database, I encountered an error at the line

```
if(course.getId()==null)
```

saying that the operator is not defined for the argument types long,null. Also tried with

```
if(course.getId()==0)
```

Same issue.

### This is the course entity/class

```
@Entity
public class Course {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

private String name;

public Course() {
}

public Course(String name) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Course [name=" + name + "]";
}
```

}

---

### This is the DAO layer

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class CourseRepository {

@Autowired
EntityManager em;

public Course findById(Long id) {
    return em.find(Course.class, id);
}

public void deleteById(Long id) {
    em.remove(findById(id));
    
}

public Course save(Course course) {
        if(course.getId()==null){ 
        em.persist(course);
    }
    else {
        em.merge(course);
    }
    return course;
}

}
```

---

### A small snippet from the console

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:794) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:345) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at com.in28minutes.jpa.hibernate.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:21) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Long.longValue()" because "this.id" is null
    at com.in28minutes.jpa.hibernate.demo.entity.Course.getId(Course.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.in28minutes.jpa.hibernate.demo.repository.CourseRepository.save(CourseRepository.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.in28minutes.jpa.hibernate.demo.repository.CourseRepository$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6d4415f4.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:779) ~[spring-aop-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:692) ~[spring-aop-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at com.in28minutes.jpa.hibernate.demo.repository.CourseRepository$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$862dd48f.save(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.in28minutes.jpa.hibernate.demo.DemoApplication.run(DemoApplication.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:791) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Long id;    
public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
```

The error is caused by your return type long instead of Long.
with long return type, it's required to convert to long from Long by method:

```
Long.longValue()
```

So that's why you got nullpointerexception when id is null. Just change the type long to Long and recheck...

change from:

```
long getId()
```

to

```
Long getId()
```

Comment: great, if it help you, please accept as answer ;).

Comment: oh my god, THANK YOU!!! wish this thread was more upvoted